# BrowserMob proxy and hosts file

Tags: selenium, proxy, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use [BrowserMob proxy](http://opensource.webmetrics.com/browsermob-proxy/) to monitor requests sent by WebDriver(Selenium) browser.

I instantiate proxy with:

```
    server = new ProxyServer(localProxyPort);       
    server.start();
```

Then I create Firefox profile which would use this proxy:

```
    FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile(); 

    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.type", 1);
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http", "localhost");
    profile.setPreference("network.proxy.http_port", localProxyPort);
```

My problem is that I have a LOT of different host mapping in my 'hosts' file.
BrowserMob proxy ignores system hosts file, and tries to resolve ips by itself.

There is a solution:

```
    server.remapHost("somehost.com", "127.0.0.1");
```

But I cant do it for every host. Is there a way to force proxy to use my system hosts mappings?

Thanks!

Leonti

Answer (score 2):

We can have several hosts re-mapping using the same function:

```
server.remapHost("somehost.com", "127.0.0.1");
server.remapHost("someotherhost.com", IP Address);
```

Comment: I know that, what I meant by "I can't do it for every host" is that I have(had :)) too many mappings to put every one of them in .remapHost() function.

Comment: You could automate conversion of your Hosts file to remapHost configuration lines.